# Data drops off from crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a report that prints data in different details sections.

[image]

In the details b section I have the "Suppress Blank section" enabled in the section expert.
There is no problem when I run the report from crystal (the report preview shows all the data).

When the same report is run from an application where nothing but just conversion of the crystal data into PDF happens, I have some data missing.

However if I disable the "Suppress Blank section", all works fine.

I am not able to resolve this, any help or pointers would be helpful. Couldn't find a similar problem reported online.

Comment: Which section data are you missing in pdf and which data you are able to view in preview

Comment: I am missing the data from all the detail section.. say there are 3 records, each with all details.. I get record 1 and 3 but not 2.. or I get record 2,3 and not 1.. its just random..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it worked after I suppressed each element separately in the detail section when it was blank.